# html auto update selection box

Tags: javascript, html

This is the part of HTML I have got to show month between Feb to Oct

```html
<div>
    <select name="interval" id="sInterval">
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option selected value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <span>*2</span>
</div>
```

So I got a JS list to contain the month info

```
var months=["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
```

and a function that add two month to the end to help shown the select box from Feb to Dec

```
function addmonth(thelist) {
thelist.push("11");
thelist.push("12");
}

addmonth(months)
```

I want the HTML become like this

```html
<div>
    <select name="interval" id="sInterval">
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option selected value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <span>*2</span>
</div>
```

How could I achieve this? is it possible? or should I do it on pure HTML? because the JS list is received from Jquery so it is necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
const targetParent = document.getElementById("sInterval")
["11","12"].forEach(month =>
const optionElement = document.createElement("option")
optionElement.innerText = month;
optionElement.setAttribute("value",month)
targetParent.append(optionElement))
```

Comment: Your method is correct, but you need a ; after ("sInterval") otherwise it will cause an error

Comment: yeah true.Normally VScode does that for me :)

Answer (score 2):

you should change menu all dynamic

in html )   `<select id="menu'> </select>`

in js - put this code on the `<body onload='menu_maker()' >`

```
let month = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
function menu_maker(){
    for (var i in month){ // rounding in list
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = month[i];
      option.innerHTML = month[i];
      option.style = 'classname'
      var select = document.getElementById('menu');
      select.appendChild(option);

}



}
```

Comment: where is your "menu" element exist? I got a problem because the select variable is null

Comment: <select></select> is my menu and I add option in that menu

Comment: ok it make sense, I may try that also

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `options` to the `select` element after updating `months` array.

If you are using `jQuery`, Then you can simply use `append()` method.

```js
var months=["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]

function addmonth( month ) {
  months.push( month );
  $("#sInterval").append(`<option value="${month}"> ${month} </option>`);
}

addmonth("11");
addmonth("12");
```